# ValueError: substring not found when using autofaiss

Tags: python, faiss

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kaili\Documents\New folder (2)\x.py", line 5, in <module>
    index, index_infos = build_index(embeddings, save_on_disk=False)
  File "C:\Users\kaili\anaconda3\envs\autofaiss_env\lib\site-packages\autofaiss\external\quantize.py", line 209, in build_index   
    embedding_reader = EmbeddingReader(
  File "C:\Users\kaili\anaconda3\envs\autofaiss_env\lib\site-packages\embedding_reader\embedding_reader.py", line 20, in __init__ 
    self.reader = NumpyReader(embeddings_folder)
  File "C:\Users\kaili\anaconda3\envs\autofaiss_env\lib\site-packages\embedding_reader\numpy_reader.py", line 67, in __init__     
    self.fs, embeddings_file_paths = get_file_list(embeddings_folder, "npy")
  File "C:\Users\kaili\anaconda3\envs\autofaiss_env\lib\site-packages\embedding_reader\get_file_list.py", line 15, in get_file_list
    return _get_file_list(path, file_format)
  File "C:\Users\kaili\anaconda3\envs\autofaiss_env\lib\site-packages\embedding_reader\get_file_list.py", line 44, in _get_file_list
    prefix = path[: path.index(path_in_fs)]
ValueError: substring not found
```

Trying to use autofaiss to create faiss indices but no matter what I always end up getting substring not found. This was me trying it on a brand new virtual environment. The code is here (taken from one of the examples off of their github)

```
from autofaiss import build_index
import numpy as np

embeddings = np.float32(np.random.rand(100, 512))
index, index_infos = build_index(embeddings, save_on_disk=False)
_, I = index.search(embeddings, 1)
print(I)
```

I have no clue where the error is coming from. If anyone could figure out what's messing up that'd be appreciated.